# Blazor Server App with Dynamic CultureInfo Saved in Cookie don't work in iFrame

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, iframe, localization, blazor

I can't share my own app for nda issue but I found this one which shows exactly the same issue

https://github.com/SyncfusionExamples/blazor-localization/tree/master/.NET6%20Blazor%20Server%20App/Localization-with-dynamic-culture
[Blazor-Localization](https://github.com/tossnet/Blazor-Localization)

This app displays a page with a **CultureSwitcher** component to select between 5 languages.

When you select a language, I can see both the page+dropdown refreshed with the selected language value.

Now, you embed the Url of this app inside a new app's page inside an iFrame and nothing works anymore.

The cookie mechanism doesn't save or/and load the value anymore.

This was working perfectly in net+core+3.1 and 5.0 but no more in net+core+6.

Is something change in security or cors or ????

Thanks in advance for any tips

-Vince

Comment: It looks like your issue is resolved by the suggestion given by Jesse. I would suggest you accept Jesse's answer to this question. It could help other community members in the future with similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with SameSite cookies. It's even documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite):

> Applications that use <iframe> may experience issues with sameSite=Lax
> or sameSite=Strict cookies because  is treated as cross-site
> scenarios.

Have you tried setting the cookie options?

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
    CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
    CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(
       new RequestCulture(culture)),
    new CookieOptions() { SameSite = SameSiteMode.None, Secure = true} );
```

Comment: Superb Jesse, it's working great now. You saved my day :-).
Cheers
-vince